# xCode Master-Detail change detail viewcontroller from master viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have just created a new "Master-Detail application" project I Xcode 5.

Then on my Master View Controller, I have change the table view to static, and added up a few items: Home, View 1, View 2.

I have removed the default databinding, so when i run it now it appears as intended.

As default my "Home" view is my Detail View Controller.

Now I would like: When i press "View 1" it changes my Detail View Controller to a new view I have created on my storyboard.

But how do I do that?

I have tried to push in my "View 1" but then i first have to go back to my Detail View, before I can get the menu to show up...

I guess I have to make my "View 1" the root controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use **segues**. You can setup them in storyboard with Interface Builder. Just remember to use *replace* segues instead of *push*:

[image]

And the code:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainSegue" sender:self];
            break;

        case 1:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sheduleSegue" sender:self];
            break;

        case 2:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapSegue" sender:self];
            break;
    }
}
```

Besides it, you can do some additional setup for each segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mainSegue"]) {
        TestViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
        dest.someNumber = 100500; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so now I have created a segues called areaSegue, from my :Split View Controller -> Detail View Controller -> Navigation Controller to my View 1. But how do I access that Navigation controller from my: Split View Controller -> Maseter View Controller -> Navigation Controller -> Master View Controller so that I can trigger my segue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understang what segue you're creating. The segues look the following way: areaSegue: MasterViewController->ViewController1; anotherSegue: MasterViewController->ViewController2;

Comment: Try to look at this picture: http://tinypic.com/r/152yigy/8 I have my Table in the Master View Controller. But the pages I want to change are lying in my Navigation Controller.. And I can't seem to access the segue from Navigation Controler to Aarea View Controller form my Table..

Comment: Why do you need all these navigation controllers? Follow the next pattern: Split View Controller -> Navigation Controller -> Master View Controller -> Detail View Controllers (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xa0yde1yaf7vbjj/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-01-30%2015.21.28.PNG)